# Executar busca no Mysql após abrir Modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, bootstrap

Galera, ontem com a ajuda do Bruno aqui da página consegui resolver minha pendência de criar o modal mas hoje estou com uma nova dificuldade, que não consegui passar por cima.

Seguinte to com meu modal abrindo com a abertura através do click normal.
Porém o que preciso é, enviar via POST a data que está num input type="date"

```
<form method="post" action="busca_relatorio.php" class="panel-heading">                         
    <!-- BUSCA CALENDARIO -->        
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">                  
       <input type="date" id="busca_data" name="busca_data" placeholder="data" class="form-control">
    </div>                  
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Buscar</button>                       
</form>
```

E tenho minha janela Modal:

```
<div  class="modal fade" id="exampleModalLong" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLongTitle" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">                      
        <!-- Modal content-->
           <div class="modal-content">
               <div class="modal-header" style="padding:35px 50px;">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                     <h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>Relatórios</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body" style="padding:40px 50px;">
                    <div id="resultado_busca">...</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Fechar</button>       
                </div>
            </div>                        
        </div>
    </div>
```

E aqui tenho meu código ajax
$('#btn_buscar').click( function(){

```
$.ajax({
    url:'busca_relatorio.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: $('#resultado_busca').serialize(),
    success: function(data){                        
        $('#resultado_busca').html(data); // data é o valor printado do lado php
        $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show') ; // abre o modal via jquery
        }
    });                     
});
```

Se eu colocar o  consigo fazer o envio do input type="date" e na página busca_relatorio.php mostra meu relatório certinho de acordo com minha busca no mysql com base na data passada.

Porém se eu troco pra button type="button" para não mudar de página e abrir na janela modal, ele já vem com a minha div carregada desde o começo, antes de fazer a requisição através da Data, e me vem um erro falando que o busca_data ainda não está definido.

Como posso fazer (Provavelmente via Ajax) para somente carregar dentro da div a resposta do SQL após o envio do input e retorno da página busca_relatorio.php?

Tentei criar algumas funções de Ajax(que ainda não manjo muito bem mas to tentando kkkk) de fazer um refresh quando clico no botão buscar, ou tentar fazer fora do document.ready mas ai nem a modal abre.

Fiquei realmente preso nessa.

Abraço galera.

Comment: Espera você quer que no momento que abra o modal execulte o ajax?

Comment: Então na verdade eu queria que a requisição de busca no banco de dados só ocorresse ao abrir a modal.

Pois meu script já está rodando e fazendo a busca ao carregar a página(Que acaba fazendo a consulta antes de saber a data do meu formulário).
Eu queria fazer essa busca somente ao abrir a modal assim meu formulário já teria sido enviado.

Answer (score 1):

Rafael,

Você pode utilizar a função [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) do jQuery para impedir que o redirecionamento seja feito. Desta maneira

```
$('#id_do_seu_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  return false; // nao ira para lugar algum 
});
```

**EDIT**

O que o script abaixo faz é somente quando seu form for "submitado" é que ele chamará o AJAX para rodar o PHP, sendo assim, ele não irá executar quando a página for carregada.

O `.submit` irá substituir o seu `$('#btn_buscar').click( function(){...`, então pode comentar ele no seu código.

**HTML:**

```
<form method="post" class="panel-heading">                         
    <!-- BUSCA CALENDARIO -->        
    <div class="col-sm-offset-4 col-sm-4">                  
       <input type="date" id="busca_data" name="busca_data" placeholder="data" class="form-control">
    </div>                  
    <button class="btn btn-info" type="button">Buscar</button>                       
</form>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#id_do_seu_form').submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
    url:'busca_relatorio.php',
    method: 'post',
    data: { busca_data: $('#busca_data').val()}, // sua data chegará como $_POST['busca_data'] no PHP.
    success: function(data){                      
        $('#resultado_busca').html(data); // data é o valor printado do lado php
        $('#exampleModalLong').modal('show') ; // abre o modal via jquery
     }
    });                     
  });
  return false; //não vai redirecionar a lugar algum
});
```

Comment: Valeu a ajuda novamente Bruno, com esse código consigo até impedir que meu código não me leve a outra página, porém ainda assim a busca ao banco de dados já é feita ao carregar a página (Antes do meu formulário enviar a data do input).

Comment: Não entendi muito bem, você quer abrir o modal quando clicar no botão busca_data e fazer a requisição via ajax só quando abrir o modal?

Comment: Está confuso mesmo, heheh.

Esse meu script tem o input com a data que espero buscar no relatório. Essa busca será feita em outro arquivo, chamado "busca_relatorio.php" lá tenho um um SELECT pro mysql onde um dos parâmetros é a data que estou enviando no input e um echo com o resultado.

Meu problema é que o SELECT está sendo feito enquanto já carrego a página e ainda não tenho essa informação da data.

De forma simples, quero que o usuário apenas escolha a data no input, e quando clicar em "buscar" abrirá uma modal e nele tenha a consulta no Banco de dados com a data que ele solicitou

Comment: Uhm entendi a intenção do código só que mesmo assim eu não tô conseguindo trazer o resultado nessa id "resultado_busca"  com o preenchimento. Na verdade, com o button type="button" nem consigo abrir a modal, se troco pra submit, ainda consigo abrir a modal mas sem resultado dentro dela.

Aliást um detalhe, trocando o botão pra Submit, ele me mostra até um script q deixei solto no meu arquivo de busca do PHP, mas por algum motivo não me vem o echo com o resultado. Mas isso deve ser algum erro no envio da data, Vou ver se consigo descobrir isso

Comment: da um echo na sua query para ver se está chegando a data lá, pega essa query e roda num client sql como php my admin ou heidi sql. Se a query der algum erro, é o motivo que não está mostrando a informação desejada

Comment: Eu fiz o teste, o problema está sendo no envio mesmo. A data não está indo no formulário. Imagino que ela vá quando uso o button, quando submit eu acabo "roubando" a cena do ajax, mas com o button não me carrega a modal. Vou ver se reescrevo essa parte do código.